# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length

Tags: java, arraylist, arguments

```java
// Driver code
public static void main(String args[]) {
  scanDictionary(args[0]);
  Node start = new Node(args[1], null);
  Node target = new Node(args[2], null);
  System.out.println("our start word was " + start.getWord() + " and our end word was " + target.getWord());

  System.out.println("here is the path we took to get there: ");
  Q.add(start);
  System.out.println(shortestChainLen(start, target));
}
```

```java
public static void scanDictionary(String fileName) {
  File file = new File("diction.txt");
  try {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    // looking through our diction file and adding them to a array list called dictionary
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
      dictionary.insertWord(scan.nextLine());
    }
    scan.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("An error has occurred");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
  }
}
```

I want it to read the diction file from my computer and scan it's contents and add them to an ArrayList. I then want to be able to easily access the contents in this list using arguments.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript

Comment: Are you passing arguments when you run it?

Comment: You should share the stacktrace of your exception, it's not clear which line we are talking about.